# Parameter not being passed on addEventListener on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

```
for(let i = 0; i <= todosToday.length - 1; i++) {
  const a = document.createElement("a");

  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showFoundTodo(todosToday[i]);
  });

}
```

This works for Chrome but not for IE, specifically IE11. The instance of the array `todosToday` on `i` does not get passed when I attach the function `showFoundTodo` in the `click` event.

```
function showFoundTodo(todo) {
   console.log(todo);
}
```

This function prints out `undefined` thus making the argument unusable. On Chrome, it outputs to the object with no problems.

I checked and only in that instance does `todosToday` become unreadable. To zero in where the change occurse, every where else I'd do a `console.log()` and it prints out the object (before the `for` loop, inside, and after it). At first I thought it was the `attachEvent` compatibility but that was for earlier versions of IE and the function also gets called. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Tip: 
for(let i = 0; i <= todosToday.length - 1; i++)

for(let i = 0; i < todosToday.length; i++) 

-- saves you some typing and (some) processing time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop variable `i` is not in the scope by the time the listener fires. The simple way to fix it is to move it to the outer scope:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i <= todosToday.length - 1; i++) {
```

The way I generally preferred when modifying the DOM directly was to add the object reference to the element.

```js
var todosToday = [ 'Wake up.', 'Kiss my wife.', 'Take a shower.' ];

for(var i = 0; i <= todosToday.length - 1; i++) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.innerText = todosToday[i];
  a.todo      = todosToday[i];

  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showFoundTodo(this.todo);
  });
  
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.appendChild(a);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function showFoundTodo(todo) {
   console.log(todo);
}
```

**Note:** You have a problem in all IE versions, BTW. `addEventListener` is not supported before IE 9 and `let` and `const` are not supported before IE 11.

Comment: thank you! I didn't think it was a scoping issue since it worked on Chrome.

Comment: It's a scoping issue because Chrome executed the listener within the scope of the `for` loop and IE executed it within the scope of the document. BTW, the Chrome way is correct so it's a bug in IE. Go figure!